# Django form "soft" validation, send back to user for explicit confirmation of doubtful data

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an integer field in a form that must be in the range 100 to 1000. However, if a value other than 100, 200, 381 (don't ask), 525 or 1000 is entered, it is *quite probable*  that this is erroneous.

What I'd like to do is what I'm calling "soft validation" -- I don't know if there is any standard terminology. The first time, the form would raise errors and then "Confirm?" boolean field(s) would be added, default `false`. If it comes back again with the confirm field(s) `true`, then unlikely data will be accepted.

The  answer [Warnings (or even info messages) instead of only errors in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270550/warnings-or-even-info-messages-instead-of-only-errors-in-django) shows how to accomplish this with custom code added field-by-field and form-by-form -- but I'd rather not do it this way. Does anybody know whether this has already been done in open-source code in a generalized, re-usable way? In my dreams, I would `raise ValidationWarning ...` (which doesn't exist) and the rest would look after itself.

I don't know what to search for with Google. I can't find anything obvious at https://djangopackages.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warnings (or even info messages) instead of only errors in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270550/warnings-or-even-info-messages-instead-of-only-errors-in-django)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but the "alternatively ..." is that answer is less code than I'd worked out, and perhaps handling soft validation form by form and field by field with a few lines of code added to each is OK. I'd still like something generic, though. In my dreams, `raise ValidationWarning...` and the rest happens as if by magic?

Comment: You're going to have to do the magic yourself. Check the form data in `request.POST` in the view/ have the validation fail during field cleaning and then redirect to a confirmation page or return the same page with an admin message. Shouldn't be more than five lines of code, I reckon. If you need this functionality more than once, make a mixin out of it and subclass as necessary.

Comment: Just use custom validation for your field, and add another auxiliary boolean field (`is_soft`, False by default, True when confirmed) to the form, to be used in that validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you find a minimal working example similar to the one given in the link in the comment. You only have to be carefully to not include the soft validation in the `clean_MagicNumber(self)` function - this is prone to race conditions because the clean_data attributes are only set. 
Instead use the overwritten `clean(self)` or `validate_unique(self)` function.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.db import models


class Autor(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    MagicNumber = models.IntegerField()


class AutorAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ConfirmMagicNumber = forms.BooleanField(label="I confirm it is the right magic number.",
                                            required=False,
                                            widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    def _field_is_active(self, field):
        if self._meta.exclude is not None and field in self._meta.exclude:
            return False
        if self._meta.fields is not None and field in self._meta.fields:
            return True
        return False

    def clean_MagicNumber(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['MagicNumber'] < 100 or self.cleaned_data['MagicNumber'] > 1000:
            raise ValidationError("Magic number outside of allowed range between 100 to 1000.")
        return self.cleaned_data['MagicNumber']

    def validate_unique(self):
        """
            We use validate unique because it is quite late in the validation process,
            after we got the values of all fields and
            actually I used it, because I was really warning for a possible duplicate
        """
        super().validate_unique()
        # only check if number does not have errors and is in form data
        if 'MagicNumber' not in self._errors and 'MagicNumber':
            # only check if confirm checkbox is given and not checked
            if ('ConfirmMagicNumber' in self.cleaned_data and 'ConfirmMagicNumber' in self.fields
                and self.cleaned_data['ConfirmMagicNumber'] is not True and self._field_is_active('ConfirmMagicNumber')):
                    if self.cleaned_data['MagicNumber'] not in (100, 200, 381, 525, 1000):
                        error_msg = "The magic number looks wrong. Please confirm it below."
                        self.add_error('MagicNumber', error_msg)
                        self.fields['ConfirmMagicNumber'].widget = forms.CheckboxInput()
                        self.fields['ConfirmMagicNumber'].required = True

@admin.register(Autor)
class AutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AutorAdminForm
```